# How to pass form model via GET in Yii 1.x

Tags: php, url, yii, get, yii1.x

How I can create URL to Yii form with existing model parameters in URL?

E.g. I have `$model` with some attributes and want get URL like this:

```
controller/formaction?Form%5Battr1%5D=VAL1&Form%5Battr2%5D=VAL2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to customize the url when you are using GET method. When you use GET method, **browser** always concatenates `name` and `value` of all inputs with your form action string. So it can't be changed. One possible solution for getting ride of ugly urls, is using POST instead of GET.

Comment: I don't want to change the submitted url of form. I just want create url to the form in another action with attributes in my Form model `$model`. E.g. when I use createUrl function (`$this->createUrl('formaction', $model)`) I get the result like this: `controller/formaction?attr1%5D=VAL1&attr2%5D=VAL2` and it doesn't parsed correctly in `formaction`.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate such URLs in this way:

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/formaction', [
    CHtml::activeName('Form', 'attr1') => 'VAL1',
    CHtml::activeName('Form', 'attr2') => 'VAL2',
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you try something like this :

```
public function action formaction(){
  $form = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('Form',false);
}
```